# .NET 4.5 Application does not start with only .NET 4.7 installed

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.5, .net-4.7

I have a C# .NET WPF (MVVM Lite) Application that runs on Windows 7 machines.
It is combiled for .NET 4.5.

While .NET 4.5.2 was installed on the clients, it run as it should.
After an client update to .NET 4.7 and uninstalling .NET 4.5.2 (!) the application hangs on start:

> Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319 Beschreibung: DThe process was terminated
>   by an unhandled exception. exception information:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException bei
>   MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(System.Guid
>   ByRef, System.Object, Int32, System.Guid ByRef) bei
>   MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreatePimcManager() bei
>   MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods..cctor()
>
> exception information: System.TypeInitializationException bei
>   MS.Win32.Penimc.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateResetEvent(IntPtr ByRef) bei
>   System.Windows.Input.PenThreadWorker..ctor() bei
>   System.Windows.Input.PenThreadPool.GetPenThreadForPenContextHelper(System.Windows.Input.PenContext)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Input.PenThreadPool.GetPenThreadForPenContext(System.Windows.Input.PenContext)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispTabletDeviceCollection.UpdateTabletsImpl()
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispTabletDeviceCollection.UpdateTablets()
>   bei System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispTabletDeviceCollection..ctor()
>   bei System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.get_WispTabletDevices()
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.RegisterHwndForInput(System.Windows.Input.InputManager,
>   System.Windows.PresentationSource) bei
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndStylusInputProvider..ctor(System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Initialize(System.Windows.Interop.HwndSourceParameters)
>   bei System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean) bei
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow() bei
>   System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow() bei
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) bei
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) bei
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32,
>   IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef) bei
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32) bei
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>   bei
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef) bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   bei
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   bei System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object) bei
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window) bei
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window) bei
>   ApplicationName.App.Main()

App.xaml.cs is modified:

```
public partial class App : Application, ISingleInstanceApp 
{

    private static string Unique = "Test_xx";

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {    
        for (int i = 1; i < Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length; i++)
            Unique += Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[i];

        if (SingleInstance<App>.InitializeAsFirstInstance(Unique))
        {
            var application = new App();
            application.InitializeComponent();
            application.Run();

            // Allow single instance code to perform cleanup operations
            SingleInstance<App>.Cleanup();
        }
    }

    public bool SignalExternalCommandLineArgs(IList<string> args)
    {
        if(args.Count < 3 || args[2].ToUpper() != "AUTOSTART")            
            MessageBox.Show("Program already runs!","Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Warning);

            Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;                
            return true;
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {            
            this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);


    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this might help https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4889

Comment: Isn't .NET 4.7 in place upgrade?

Comment: @MikeT Thank you for the link. But the application (binaries) did not change for over 1 month. The issue came over night (last week).